# Trailing widget consumes entire tile width. Please use a sized widget, or consider replacing ListTile with a custom widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a basic shopping app .My idea is to make a list tile of my products so that I could  edit or delete  the products . So when i navigated to that page it showed a blank white page with the error as shown in the picture
[Blank Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yvmM.jpg)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eRDy.jpg)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserProductItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;
  UserProductItem(this.title, this.imageUrl);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(title),
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imageUrl),
      ),
      trailing: Row(
        children: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
            onPressed: () {},
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            onPressed: () {},
            color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had this issue as well and was able to fix it by setting `mainAxisSize` to `MainAxisSize.min` in the `Row`:

```dart
trailing: Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
        onPressed: () {},
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      ),
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
        onPressed: () {},
        color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: love you <33 thanks

Answer (score 20):

Wrapping `trailing`  with a `Container` may give you some kind of warnings, so the best option is to `wrap` it with `SizedBox` and give it a `height` and `width`

```
trailing: SizedBox(
              height: 100, width: 100, child: Image.network(item.imgurl)),
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your answer in a FittedBox like so

```
      trailing: FittedBox(
    child: Row(
      children: [
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
        ),
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
          color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

You should discover that the Row have unlimited width. Therefore you need to fit it into the available size of a given device.

Answer (score 2):

What I did was I wrapped the row (trailing: Row()) with a container and gave it a specific width

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserProductItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;
  UserProductItem(this.title, this.imageUrl);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(title),
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imageUrl),
        ),
        trailing: Container(
          width: 100,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                onPressed: () {},
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                onPressed: () {},
                color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs about the `tailing` property:

```dart
/// To show right-aligned metadata (assuming left-to-right reading order;
/// left-aligned for right-to-left reading order), consider using a [Row] with
/// [CrossAxisAlignment.baseline] alignment whose first item is [Expanded] and
/// whose second child is the metadata text, instead of using the [trailing]
/// property.
```

I believe you should not be using a ListTile if you need to have 2 icons on the right. Instead, you should implement your custom widget with Rows.

EDIT:

Something like:

```dart
InkWell( // Only wrap with an Inkwell if you need to add a click for the entire Row
  onTap: ...
  child: Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
    children: [
      CircleAvatar(...),
      Expanded(child: Text(title)),
      Row(
        children: [
          IconButton1,
          IconButton2,
        ],
      ),
    ]
  ),
)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. What I did was I wrapped the row (trailing: Row()) with a container and gave it a specific width

Answer (score 0):

The error occuring because of leading. Just wrap the image avatar with a container and give it a width

leading: Container(width:50, child: CircleAvatar(
backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imageUrl),
),)

Answer (score 0):

based on @Gpack answer a proper solution whould be using `Row` in title or substile parameter of a `listTile`.

```dart
ListTile(
      onTap: () {
        
      },
      title: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
        textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                text: 'Subtitle: ',
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .bodyMedium!
                    .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                children: [
                  TextSpan(
                      text: description,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium)
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),

           IconButton(
             visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
             onPressed: () {
             },
             icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
             tooltip: 'add1',
           ),
           IconButton(
             visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
             onPressed: () {
             },
             icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
             tooltip: 'add2',
           ),

      ),
      subtitle: Text('sample'),
      isThreeLine: true,
      // trailing: Row(
      //         mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      //         children: [
      //           IconButton(
      //             visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
      //             onPressed: () {
      //             },
      //             icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
      //             tooltip: 'add1',
      //           ),
      //           IconButton(
      //             visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
      //             onPressed: () {
      //             },
      //             icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
      //             tooltip: 'add2',
      //           ),
      //         ],
      //       )

    );
```

If you have one widget in trailing and get the same error try to use `FittedBox` like this:

```dart
trailing: FittedBox(
  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
  child: CircularProgressIndicator());
```